# Why was this answer and question deleted

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions

Here's the A2A question that was deleted.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139597

As far as I can tell, this is a question that isn't present on the site. No reason was given why the question was deleted either. How come?

Comment: The majority of the users regular to this site (including meta) are not privileged to see deleted posts (because they don't meet the criteria needed), so consider providing screenshots of the whole question and the answers listed there. That should help us not successfully closing this post with the reason: "unclear what you're asking". Please do not miss anything to post. Thank you!

Comment: You appear to have a propensity for posting self-answered questions that link to your site/blog. We have some standards for [properly disclosing your affiliation in such cases](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) that are seemingly absent in your posts. I would wager that this was a significant factor here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were flagged as spam and automatically deleted by the system (the Community user).

Please refer to [the link eldarerathis posted](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) for more information on why your posts were not acceptable.