# All my reputation is missing

Tags: discussion

This question belongs in meta but it seems all my reputation has disappeared so I can't post in meta (needs minimum 5 reps). I request moderators to move this question to meta.

Last time I checked I had about 200 reputation. Now all that has disappeared making me desperate enough to post this question here. There is no record of any penalty in the reputation tab either.

Kindly resolve this issue.

PS: I have already flagged the question for a move.

Answer (score 4):

Just as [was explained on your previous Meta question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/why-was-this-answer-and-question-deleted), several self-answered questions of yours were deleted because they appeared to exist primarily to promote your website/blog. Some of these were deleted because:

> They were flagged as spam and automatically deleted by the system (the Community user).

This flag carries a [100 point reputation penalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor/58035#58035) for the account that posted the content.

This is a deliberate mechanism put in place to reflect the fact that the community has lost trust in the flagged account, and isn't something that can be reversed. You would likely need to [appeal to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), but note that I do not guarantee that they will agree to take any action, particularly if they deem that the flags were valid.